# lesscss-maven-plugin from biz.gabrys.maven.plugins : using <compilerOptions>

Tags: css, less, maven-plugin

I succeed to compile less to css. But i cannot figure out how pass Compiler Options to the compiler in order to generate the mapping source file too.

From the doc, it should be a thing like :

```
<compilerOptions>
  <compilerOption>dumpLineNumbers:all</compilerOption>
</compilerOptions>
```

But i get :

```
[INFO] Compiling 1 source to C:\workspaces\neon-dev\project\src\main\webapp\css
lesscss: couldn't open file dumpLineNumbers:all
```

Any hints ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass options in `command line` style, e.g.:

```
<compilerOptions>
    <compilerOption>--line-numbers=all</compilerOption>
</compilerOptions>
```

See all available options: http://lesscss.org/usage/index.html#command-line-usage-options.

---

Version 2.0 of the `biz.gabrys.maven.plugins:lesscss-maven-plugin` will have a simpler configuration e.g.:

```
<options>
    <lineNumbers>all</lineNumbers>
</options>
```

Comment: Thanks, i tryed these options :     <compilerOption>--source-map</compilerOption>    <compilerOption>--source-map=style.css.map</compilerOption> but that produce this error :  Error: SyntaxError: Cannot find module './encoder.js'

Comment: The plugin 1.X does not support source maps. Luckily version 2.X will allow to generate source maps (see [Support for Source Maps](https://github.com/gabrysbiz/lesscss-compiler/issues/3)).